# How to overwrite a class-library button for drop down (Angular 4+)?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using the Angular Material library for a drop-down navigation bar. 
The problem is that I would like to hover through the list. I cannot change the style in HTML, but can easily do it in Chrome.

```css
/* Class set by Angular Material itself */

button.mat-menu-item:hover {
    width: 100%;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <a href="https://google.com"><button mat-menu-item>Help</button></a>
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="Logout()">Sign Out</button>
</mat-menu>
```

When I set this in CSS, it doesn't work. I tried giving it class, but it doesn't work.

Comment: add your own class and own css style, and add !important at the end before semicolon?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work

Comment: @EvikGhazarian don't use important! its bad practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
button {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
              <a href="https://google.com"><button mat-menu-item>Help</button></a>
              <button mat-menu-item (click)="Logout()">Sign Out</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: This worked. The issue was that I had to put it outside my nested CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Because of angular style encapsulation. Like @devpato mentioned, you must use `::ng-deep` to archive the styling you want for the mat button component.

But it important to understand that using `::ng-deep` alone will apply that style to all button with `.mat-menu-item` class in your app.

So if you want the style to effect to a specific component only, use `:host` before it (the `:host` mean the component that is hosting mat button component )

```
:host ::ng-deep button.mat-menu-item:hover {
   ....
}
```

Comment: I am using Angular 8, do you know if this works with Angular 8 or this Angular JS?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

using ::ng-deep. It will be replaticated at some point but it works right now.

```
::ng-deep button.mat-menu-item:hover {
    width: 100%;
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: I am using Angular 8

Comment: That's fine. Still not replecated even on Angular 9rc. This should work :)